# VBS: InputBox position doesn't correlate properly with screen size retrieved from WMIC

Tags: vbscript, screen-resolution, wmic

This batch code retrieves the screen width and screen height, in the format "WIDTH x HEIGHT"

```
@echo off
setlocal
for /f %%A in ('wmic path Win32_VideoController get CurrentHorizontalResolution^,CurrentVerticalResolution /value ^| find "="') do set "%%A"
echo %CurrentHorizontalResolution% x %CurrentVerticalResolution%
```

Now, given the output of the above returns "1920 x 1080", the below VBScript Code should spawn an `InputBox` in the lower-right corner of the screen.

```
InputBox "","Title","",1920,1080
```

However, it doesn't. This is because the `PosX` and `PosY` variables in the VBS InputBox function are measured in `Twips` instead of `Pixels`.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.interaction.inputbox?view=netframework-4.8

Is there any way to convert `Pixels` to `Twips` with only Batch and VBScript?

Answer (score 1):

I came across a solution while creating an error message customization program. The idea is to take a second pair of values from WMIC, known as "PixelsPerXLogicalInch" and "PixelsPerYLogicalInch"

```
for /f %%A in ('wmic path Win32_DesktopMonitor get PixelsPerXLogicalInch^,PixelsPerYLogicalInch /value ^| find "="') do set "%%A"
echo %PixelsPerXLogicalInch% x %PixelsPerYLogicalInch%
```

This will output a conversion factor for converting pixels to inches. Since a twip is just 1/1440th of an inch, dividing these values into 1440 will result in the number of twips per pixel.

```
for /f %%A in ('wmic path Win32_DesktopMonitor get PixelsPerXLogicalInch^,PixelsPerYLogicalInch /value ^| find "="') do set "%%A"
set /a TwipsPerPixelX=1440/%PixelsPerXLogicalInch%
set /a TwipsPerPixelY=1440/%PixelsPerYLogicalInch%
echo %TwipsPerPixelX% x %TwipsPerPixelY%
```

Now, just apply those conversion factors to the positional calculations with a little multiplication.

```
@echo off
setlocal
for /f %%A in ('wmic path Win32_VideoController get CurrentHorizontalResolution^,CurrentVerticalResolution /value ^| find "="') do set "%%A"
for /f %%A in ('wmic path Win32_DesktopMonitor get PixelsPerXLogicalInch^,PixelsPerYLogicalInch /value ^| find "="') do set "%%A"
set /a TwipX=%CurrentHorizontalResolution%*(1440/%PixelsPerXLogicalInch%)
set /a TwipY=%CurrentVerticalResolution%*(1440/%PixelsPerYLogicalInch%)
echo %TwipX% x %TwipY%
```

The output values from this set of commands will produce an InputBox just beyond the screen's bottom right corner (as windows are positioned from the top left corner.)

Taking all that into account, you could create a script that spawns an `InputBox` in a random position on-screen. That, or prompt the user for a position value, or even use this in your own CMD/VBS applications to position your Input Boxes more accurately.

```
<!-- :
  @echo off
  setlocal
  for /f %%A in ('wmic path Win32_VideoController get CurrentHorizontalResolution^,CurrentVerticalResolution /value ^| find "="') do set "%%A"
  for /f %%A in ('wmic path Win32_DesktopMonitor get PixelsPerXLogicalInch^,PixelsPerYLogicalInch /value ^| find "="') do set "%%A"
  set /a RandX=(%Random%*%CurrentHorizontalResolution%/32768)*(1440/%PixelsPerXLogicalInch%)
  set /a RandY=(%Random%*%CurrentVerticalResolution%/32768)*(1440/%PixelsPerYLogicalInch%)
  start /b cscript //nologo "%~f0?.wsf" "%RandX%" "%RandY%"
  exit /b
-->

<job><script language="VBScript">
  InputBox "","Randomly-Positioned Input Box","",Wscript.Arguments(0),Wscript.Arguments(1)
</script></job>
```